# Windows Batch Script to find a variable contains string or Variable has values

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I have a Variable in my Batch `%rev%`

I need to check whether it contains a string "new"
or it has a value of random numbers in it.

Any help Appreciated.

I was trying with the below code but it doesnt work.

```
if /I "%rev%"=="new" (
echo String has new
) else (
echo it doesnt has new
)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try with :

```
if /I "%rev:new=%" neq "%rev%" (
echo String has new
) else (
echo it doesnt has new
)
```

or with (a little bit slower):

```
(echo(%rev%)|find /i "new" >nul && (
  echo String has new
)||(
  echo it doesnt has new 
)
```

Comment: Ok thanks It Works. And one more query. I was trying to goto :itworks when i found new character, instead of echo. But it throws me syntax error. Could u pls help. Thanks Alot. Actually i was pretty new in Batch

Comment: @can you show your code ? I cannot be sure where the error comes from

Comment: hi npocmaka, i managed somehow. But this Batch script is rolling my head. I have some other queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744084/batch-script-to-store-certain-output-details-in-a-variable. Could u pls have a look on this link. Thanks Alot !