# Batch script to store certain output details in a Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Could someone help me in this Batch script.

I need to run the below command svn info and to get certain details in a variable.

```
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Users\jslevin\Desktop\SQL
URL: https://ofss220383.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/FCUBS_TEST/Soft/AM/SQL
Relative URL: ^/branches/FCUBS_TEST/Soft/AM/SQL
Repository Root: https://ofss220383.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO
Repository UUID: 866b0b85-a196-4771-a359-d37e344426b2
Revision: 47
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: john.levin@oracle.com
Last Changed Rev: 47
Last Changed Date: 2016-04-11 18:01:56 +0530 (Mon, 11 Apr 2016)

Var1 = SVN_DEMO (This variable should hold the Repository Root: line and should get the Last word i.e., SVN_DEMO)

Var2 = FCUBS_TEST (Should grep URL: and hold the word after branches alone i.e., FCUBS_TEST)
```

And i'm creating some temp files in my script. at the end of script i need to find any available files and should delete it.

Comment: where is the batch script, you need help with?

Comment: @Stephan, I use awk, grep  to achieve my target in shell but wondering how to use findstr and grep in batch to achieve my result. Any idea Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

probably even easier with unix-tools, but no big challenge with pure batch (kept it simple without optimizations):

```
@echo off
REM get the two important lines into variables:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find "Repository Root" file.txt') do set var1=%%a
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find "Relative URL" file.txt') do set var2=%%a

:loop
REM var1 - remove from the beginning until (including) the first '/':
set var1=%var1:*/=%
REM if there is another '/' then do it again:
if "%var1%" neq "%var1:/=%" goto :loop
REM kind of "brute force", isn't it?

REM var2: remove from the beginning until (including) 'branches/':
set var2=%var2:*branches/=%
REM take the first token by '/' as delimiter:
for /f "delims=/" %%a in ("%var2%") do set var2=%%a

set var
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your Idea made me to modify and get the results what i was expecting. So here is my Code........................................... .for /f "tokens=4 delims=//" %%i in ('findstr /ilc:"Repository Root" "svninfo"') do (
set var1=%%i
)
for /f "tokens=3 delims=^/" %%j in ('findstr /ilc:"Relative URL" "svninfo"') do (
set var2=%%j
)
echo %var1% 1>&2
echo %var2% 1>&2
exit 1

Comment: be careful: `tokens=` will give false results, if your path has another depth. That's why I didn't use `tokens`. and just took "the last from repository" and "next to 'branches' ".

Comment: @Stephen, The character length i need to fetch will always be stable. So i guess it will not be trouble for me.. Will it misbehave in this case also ?. By the way Thank U very much for your support.